# How to write multi key push in spring data mongodb?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I've the following aggregation query in mongodb:

```
{"$group": {"_id": "$code", "statusCount": {"$push": {"status": "$status", "count":"$total" }}}}
```

How can I write the `$push` part in spring data mongodb?

Answer (score 1):

I've found how to do this. Hope it'll help others also:

```
DBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
dbObject.put("status", "$status");
dbObject.put("total", "$total");

Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
                group("code").push(dbObject).as("statusCount")
        );
```